# xpath and self closing <br/>

Tags: php, xpath

Can anyone tell me how I can access the text after the < br / > in the following?

```
<li>
  <span class="title">Size</span>
  <p>Ladies<br />Case Diameter: 27.0 mm</p>
</li>
```

For some reason, I cannot get past it... however, I CAN get whats in front of it (Ladies)

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a correct XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted text node. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/p/br/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

**Do note the problem with the expression**:

```
/li/p/br/following-sibling::text()
```

Depending on the XML document this may select more than one (actually all) text-node following siblings of `br`, however you only want the text node that immediately follows `br`.

Comment: @mike: I *can* tell you, but to do this, you have to provide the XML document against which you evaluate the XPath expression. Are you sure you want to use `following::p` and not `following-sibling::p` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
/li/p/br/following-sibling::text()
```

You could also use:

```
/li/p/text()[2]
```

You may want to narrow it down to a specific `"<p>"` by using a predicate.

Comment: I've tried both of these with no luck. it still just returns whats in front of the < br / >... the full expression looks like this: /html/body/ul[@class='techlist']/li/span[text()='Size']/following::p/br/following-sibling::text() - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with dirt xml closing tag.  Eliminate the white space in `<br />` and you will see it fixed.  Thus, `<br />` should be `<br/>`.

Comment: Really?  You must have written your own XML parser.  `<br />` is perfectly good XML, and any quality parser handles it.