# How to parse HTML 'br' tag with PHP DomXpath?

Tags: php, html, parsing, domxpath

I have the following HTML example to parse with PHP and having trouble trying to parse the data between the 'br' tags:

```
<div id="dump-list">    
<div class="dump-row"> 
 <div class="dump-location odd" data-jmapping="{id: 35, point: {lng: -73.00898601, lat: 41.71727402}, category: 'office'}">

    <div class="SingleLinkNoTx">
    <a href="#10" class="loc-link">Acme Software</a><br/><strong>John Doe, MBA</strong><br/>123 Main St.<br />New York, NY 10036<br /><strong class="telephone">(212) 555-1234</strong><br/>
    </div><!-- END.SingleLinkNoTx -->

    <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" class="web_link">Visit Website</a><span><br />(0.3 miles)</span>   
    <div class="loc-info">
             <div class="loc-info-text ">
        John Doe, MBA<br /><a href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr=41.71727402,-73.00898601" target="_blank">Get Directions &raquo;</a>    
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This PHP code fragment:

```
//a[@class="loc-link"]//text()
```

handles to parse the 'a href' tag, but what about the 'br'? I've tried this:

```
//br[@class="loc-link"]//text()
```

but this doesn't return any output.

How can I parse following `HTML` to extract the data (company name, owner, street address, city, state, zip code) between the `<br />` tags?

```
<div class="SingleLinkNoTx">
<a href="#10" class="loc-link">Acme Software</a><br/><strong>John Doe, MBA</strong>  <br/>123 Main St.<br />New York, NY 10036<br /><strong class="telephone">(212) 555- 1234</strong><br/>
</div><!-- END.SingleLinkNoTx -->
```

Comment: Your second xpath doesn't return anything because `<br />` is self closing and has no content.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5094638/82769 the `following-sibling` operator may be of use.